# What's the difference between $f \circ g $ and $(f \circ g )(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, notation

I don't understand what's the meaning of writing $f \circ g $ instead of $(f\circ g)(x)$. For example in my book it says that in order to proof that the composition is associative we should proof $f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h $ but in the proof it's used the notation with x i.e. $f \circ (g \circ h)(x)=...$. Why is it so?

Comment: $f\circ g$ is a function.  $(f\circ g)(x)$ is the value this function takes at $x$.  In your book's proof, it is shown that the functions $f\circ (g\circ h)$ and $(f\circ g)\circ h$ are equal by showing that they take the same values (which is the definition of equality for functions).

Comment: What's the difference between $f$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: @Slade I did not see your comment when I posted. If you repost as an answer, I can delete mine.

Answer (score 3):

$f\circ g$ refers to a *function*. $f\circ g(x)$ is the result of *evaluating* the function $f\circ g$ at a point $x$.

In order to show that two functions are equal, it suffices to show that they are equal when evaluated at every point of their (common) domains. In your case, this means that you want to show that $(f\circ(g\circ h))(x) = ((f\circ g)\circ h)(x)$ for each $x$ in the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)